# How to rewind a video in OpenCV Python in 2019?

Tags: python, opencv

I know there are many similar questions asked in 2012 or something.

It is 2019, and in 2012, the only solution was to store the frames in memory or write them and then read them in reverse order.

But I was wondering, if there is a new function to read OpenCV frames in reverse order.

I am looking for a solution something like this:

```
if rewind == False:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
else:
    ret,frame = cap.read(rewind=True)
```

Any solution similar to this one?

or something like this:

```
if rewind == False:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
else:
    cap.goBackOneFrame()
    ret,frame = cap.read()
```

**Edit:**

I tried

```
if rewind == False:
    ret, frame = cap.read()   #Read frame
    counter += 1
else:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, counter-1)
    counter -= 1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

and it works, but the rewind speed is slow. I think my PC is taking more time in processing it?

Comment: The solution in your edit is roughly what I'd suggest. I think it can be tweaked to be faster, but this is inherently going to be slower as you're fighting against the default behavior.

Comment: What tweaks can make it faster?

Comment: I will be using this program daily, so any tweak will be very good

Comment: Unfortunately I remembered something in the OpenCV documentation so my idea for tweaking it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
# Grab the current frame.
my_check , vid = cap.read()
# use counter variable for
# Counting frames
counter = 0
check = True
frame_list = []
 while(check == True):
   cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" %counter , vid)
   check , vid = cap.read()
   frame_list.append(vid)
   # increment the counter by 1
   counter += 1
frame_list.pop()
# looping in the List of frames.
for frame in frame_list:
   # show the frame.
   cv2.imshow("Frame" , frame)
   if cv2.waitKey(25) and 0xFF == ord("q"):
      break
cap.release()
# close any open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
frame_list.reverse()
for frame in frame_list:
   cv2.imshow("Frame" , frame)
   if cv2.waitKey(25) and 0xFF == ord("q"):
      break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: But first I need to process the whole video, store frames in either memory or storage. I don't want that, I want real-time rewind without this expense....Like VLC

Comment: I edited my question.....The last part seems to be working, but it is a bit slow, any idea why?